# How to define the dilatation rate (strain) between two particles knowing the instantaneous positions and velocities?

Tags: kinematics

Provided that I have the instantaneous positions and velocities of two particles that can separate in 3D with respect to time. I would like to characterize the change in length. What could be a good formulation for that? Thanks.

Comment: change in length of what?

Comment: @Danu yeap. In order to characterize the separation of these two particles. Thanks!

Comment: you mean the distance between two points? Use pythagoras' theorem...

Comment: @Danu I need to characterize the rate of translation between the two particles. I would like to know hoe do they separate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let us use $\square_1$ and $\square_2$ to indicate stuff linked to particle 1 and 2. Let $\vec{r_{12}}$ be $\vec{r_2} - \vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{1_{r_{12}}}=\frac{\vec{r_{12}}}{\| r_{12}\|}$.

Basic vector analysis indicates that the change in length is given by: 
$$\frac{d\| r_{12}\|}{dt}=\vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{1_{r_{12}}}-\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{1_{r_{12}}}$$ with $\vec{v_i}$ and $\vec{1_{r_{12}}}$ potentially changing over time.